# Minted comments too long

Tags: minted, comments, overfull

I'm working with in the Overleaf environnement.

I have a problem with the length of my minted codes and don't know how to solve it:
[image: The comment isto long]

I used a simple code called "test.m":

```
function [x] = test(a)
  x = a + 2 % Here is a very very very long comment which is going to cause me a lot of trouble
endfunctin
```

And invoqued it with:

```
\inputminted{octave}{test.m}
```

I'm using the "minted" package and `\usemintedstyle{colorful}`.
How could I make the comment jump to the next line ?

Comment: Have you tried the option `breaklines`?

Comment: How do I invoke it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`breaklines` is a `minted` option inherited from `fvextra` package, one of its dependencies. You can use `breaklines` in multiple places:

- `\setminted{<options>}`,
- `\setmintedinline{<options>}`,
- `\begin{minted}[<options>]{<language>}`
- `\inputminted[<options>]{<language>}{<file>}`

Check its package manual for more info: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf

```tex
\begin{filecontents}[noheader, force]{test.m}
function [x] = test(a)
  x = a + 2 % Here is a very very very long comment which is going to cause me a lot of trouble
endfunctin
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\setminted{breaklines}

\begin{document}
\inputminted{matlab}{test.m}
\end{document}
```

[image]